# Add text to div - field focus

Tags: jquery, html, focus

I am trying to do, so when a user marks/put focus on an input field, a div should appear below with text. Currently I have this:

```
    <div class="field">
        <label for="email" class="label">E-mail:</label> 
        <input id="email" name="email" size="50" id="emailField" type="email" value="" />
    </div>                    

    <div id="emailNoti"></div>
```

This is my current JS code:

```
$("#emailField").focus(function() {
  $("#emailNoti").html("You have now pressed the field. Start typing");
});
```

Yet nothing happens. No div appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input has two IDs which is illegal and the reason why you can not select it with `$("#emailField")`. Remove `id="email"` or `id="emailField"`.

*Furthermore you can use the `text()` method instead of `html()` when inserting text only.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#emailField").focus(function() {
 $("#emailField").after('<div id="emailNoti" >You have now pressed the field. Start typing</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ids in your input. Remove `id='email'` from the input and your code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="email" name="email" size="50" id="emailField" type="email" value="" />
```

You have 2 ID's set, which is illegal. Try this instead:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="emailField" class="label">E-mail:</label> 
    <input name="email" size="50" id="emailField" type="email" value="" />
</div>                    

<div id="emailNoti"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input have two ID. So the first is used by the browser.

Replace with that:

```
<input id="emailField" name="email" size="50" type="email" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change ur html

```
<div class="field">
<label for="email" class="label">E-mail:</label> 
<input name="email" size="50" id="emailField" type="email" value="" />
</div>                    

<div id="emailNoti"></div>
```

working code here
   http://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/srZZf/